# group-starting-with not working as I expect it to

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to convert a cals table to a series of lists and I am struggling with grouping.

The table consists of a couple of heading rows (thead/row), and a bunch of body rows (tbody/row). There are 2 types of body row:
a) a standard data row, and 
b) a straddle heading row which 'break up' the table visually delineating each section.

I want to create a new list for each section and so am using

```
<xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="row/entry/hd4" select="table/tgroup/tbody/row">
```

I have tried various options in the group-starting-with attribute including

```
entry/@nameend
entry[@nameend]
entry/hd4
entry[hd4]
```

From my background reading on this, I note that the value should be a *pattern*, and not a *condition*, so I'm guessing the predicates are wrong.

```
<anch fac="yes">
   <p/>
   <calstable>
      <table frame="none">
         <tgroup cols="4" colsep="0" rowsep="0">
            <colspec colname="1" colnum="1" colwidth="39pt" align="center"/>
            <colspec colname="2" colnum="2" colwidth="39pt" align="center"/>
            <colspec colname="3" colnum="3" colwidth="45pt" align="center"/>
            <colspec colname="4" colnum="4" colwidth="33pt" align="center"/>
            <thead>
               <row valign="bottom">
                  <entry align="center">Anchorage</entry>
                  <entry align="center">Lat.</entry>
                  <entry align="center">Long.</entry>
                  <entry align="center">Draft</entry>
               </row>
               <row valign="bottom">
                  <entry align="center">No.</entry>
                  <entry align="center">(S)</entry>
                  <entry align="center">(E)</entry>
                  <entry align="center">(m.)</entry>
                  <entry> </entry>
               </row>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <row>
                  <entry align="left" namest="1" nameend="4"> 
                     <hd4>Outer</hd4> 
                  </entry>
               </row>
               <row>
                  <entry>O1</entry>
                  <entry>17° 57.0&#8242;</entry>
                  <entry>122° 04.0&#8242;</entry>
                  <entry>9.5</entry>
               </row>
               <row>
                  <entry>O2</entry>
                  <entry>17° 56.0&#8242;</entry>
                  <entry>122° 04.0&#8242;</entry>
                  <entry>9.5</entry>
               </row>
               <row>
                  <entry>O3</entry>
                  <entry>17° 55.0&#8242;</entry>
                  <entry>122° 04.0&#8242;</entry>
                  <entry>7.0</entry>
               </row>
               <row>
                  <entry align="left" namest="1" nameend="4"> 
                     <hd4>Gantheaume Bay</hd4> 
                  </entry>
               </row>
               <row>
                  <entry>G1</entry>
                  <entry>17° 56.5&#8242;</entry>
                  <entry>122° 10.0&#8242;</entry>
                  <entry>8.0</entry>
               </row>
               <row>
                  <entry>G2</entry>
                  <entry>17° 55.0&#8242;</entry>
                  <entry>122° 10.0&#8242;</entry>
                  <entry>8.0</entry>
               </row>
               <row>
                  <entry>G2</entry>
                  <entry>17° 56.5&#8242;</entry>
                  <entry>122° 09.5&#8242;</entry>
                  <entry>8.0</entry>
               </row>
            </tbody>
         </tgroup>
      </table>
   </calstable>
</anch>
```

and the xslt as follows

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0"
>    
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" standalone="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <anch>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="anch/calstable" mode="cals-to-list"/>
        </anch>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="calstable[//thead[count(row) = 2]]" mode="cals-to-list">
        <xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="row/entry/hd4" select="table/tgroup/tbody/row">
            <list>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="cals-to-list"/>
            </list>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tbody/row[entry[@nameend]]" mode="cals-to-list">
        <xsl:variable name="lhtype">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="entry/hd2">2</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="entry/hd3">3</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="entry/hd4">4</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>2</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <lh lhtype="{$lhtype}">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="entry[@nameend]" mode="cals-to-list"/>
        </lh>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="tbody/row[not(entry[@nameend])]" mode="cals-to-list">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="entry" mode="cals-to-list"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row/entry[@nameend]" mode="cals-to-list">
        <xsl:value-of select="*/text()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row/entry[not(@nameend)]" mode="cals-to-list">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="thead-rows" select="count(ancestor::*[local-name()='tgroup']/thead/row)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="top-line" select="normalize-space(ancestor::*[local-name()='tgroup']/thead/row[position() != $thead-rows]/entry[$pos]/text())"/>
        <xsl:variable name="bot-line" select="normalize-space(ancestor::*[local-name()='tgroup']/thead/row[$thead-rows]/entry[$pos]/text())"/>
        <xsl:variable name="unit" select="normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after($bot-line,'('),')'))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$top-line"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$unit"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>



 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I get

```
<anch xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <list>
      <lh lhtype="4">Outer</lh>
      <li>Anchorage O1  Lat. 17° 57.0′ S Long. 122° 04.0′ E Draft 9.5 m. </li>
      <li>Anchorage O2  Lat. 17° 56.0′ S Long. 122° 04.0′ E Draft 9.5 m. </li>
      <li>Anchorage O3  Lat. 17° 55.0′ S Long. 122° 04.0′ E Draft 7.0 m. </li>
      <lh lhtype="4">Gantheaume Bay</lh>
      <li>Anchorage G1  Lat. 17° 56.5′ S Long. 122° 10.0′ E Draft 8.0 m. </li>
      <li>Anchorage G2  Lat. 17° 55.0′ S Long. 122° 10.0′ E Draft 8.0 m. </li>
      <li>Anchorage G2  Lat. 17° 56.5′ S Long. 122° 09.5′ E Draft 8.0 m. </li>
   </list>
</anch>
```

But I would expect the list to break and restart a new list just before the Gantheaume Bay entry.

Can someone explain where I've gone wrong and what the correct pattern should be?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting `row` elements with the `xsl:for-each-group` and so the `group-starting-with` must also be a `row` element (representing the first one each in group).

Change your `xsl:for-each-group` to this...

```
<xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="row[entry/hd4]" select="table/tgroup/tbody/row">
```

Comment: To expand this a little, the `select` attribute is an expression that selects the nodes to be grouped (the "population"), and the `group-starting-with` attribute is a pattern that matches those nodes that form the start of a new group. So the pattern is only useful if it matches nodes in the population. Since the nodes in your population are all named "row", and since your pattern only matches nodes named "hd4", it can't be useful.